# Android build fail - FormatException

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-build

After switching from Unity 2018.1.something to 2018.2.0.b3 I can no longer build for Android, I get:

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Before switching to the newest beta version I was able to create a build without any problems (although not with gradle, but with internal build system). Has anyone experienced this problem and/or can someone help me figure this out?

This is the whole message I get:

```
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
System.Version+VersionResult.SetFailure (System.Version+ParseFailureKind failure, System.String argument) (at <e1a80661d61443feb3dbdaac88eeb776>:0)
System.Version.TryParseComponent (System.String component, System.String componentName, System.Version+VersionResult& result, System.Int32& parsedComponent) (at <e1a80661d61443feb3dbdaac88eeb776>:0)
System.Version.TryParseVersion (System.String version, System.Version+VersionResult& result) (at <e1a80661d61443feb3dbdaac88eeb776>:0)
System.Version.Parse (System.String input) (at <e1a80661d61443feb3dbdaac88eeb776>:0)
System.Version..ctor (System.String version) (at <e1a80661d61443feb3dbdaac88eeb776>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Utils.ParseVersion (System.String version) (at <a03b4d5bdb8646db9fef40240e67bcbf>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidComponentProperties.get_PackageRevision () (at <a03b4d5bdb8646db9fef40240e67bcbf>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidComponentProperties.GetPackageRevision (System.String directory) (at <a03b4d5bdb8646db9fef40240e67bcbf>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.BuildToolsVersion () (at <a03b4d5bdb8646db9fef40240e67bcbf>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKBuildToolsDetector.GetVersion (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools sdkTools, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools) (at <a03b4d5bdb8646db9fef40240e67bcbf>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKComponentDetector.Detect (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools sdkTools, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.Version minVersion, UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.ProgressHandler onProgress) (at <a03b4d5bdb8646db9fef40240e67bcbf>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK.EnsureSDKComponentVersion (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.Version minVersion, UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKComponentDetector detector) (at <a03b4d5bdb8646db9fef40240e67bcbf>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK.EnsureSDKComponentVersion (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.Int32 minVersion, UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKComponentDetector detector) (at <a03b4d5bdb8646db9fef40240e67bcbf>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <a03b4d5bdb8646db9fef40240e67bcbf>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <a03b4d5bdb8646db9fef40240e67bcbf>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PrepareForBuild (UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at <a03b4d5bdb8646db9fef40240e67bcbf>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PrepareForBuild (UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at <a03b4d5bdb8646db9fef40240e67bcbf>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.PrepareForBuild (UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:106)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: That sounds like a bug that should be reported to Unity.

Comment: provide your code.

Comment: @AndroidTeam What code? I can't provide the whole project and I don't even know where to start with this message

Answer (score 0):

This may be because your "Target API" is set to "Automatic (Highest Installed)". If you had it Android P installed as your highest API, then you should change the Target API setting to something else. I set mine to "Android 8.1 (Oreo)".

Answer (score 0):

I am using Unity Version 2019.1.9f1. After getting this error I have been searching to get proper solution and some of few is telling to change Unity system file with proper Format coding. But before doing the System file editing just restart my macOS and Unity3D also then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by changing the USB port that the device is plugged into.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the adb.exe proccess from the task manager and try again